# How to find hardcoded values defined in text using MS SQL query without using functions

Tags: sql-server

Requirement: I have a table for storing queries (SQL programs). I need to search and find out in this table such queries which have hardcoded values for a particular column (name) as shown below:

```sql
SELECT
        *
        FROM TABLE1 AC
        WHERE 
        AC.name = 'hardcoded_value1'
        UNION
        SELECT 
        * 
        FROM TABLE2 BC
        WHERE BC.name = 'hardcoded_value2'
```

I have tried and done this using a function and it works fine. But the requirement has a constraint which doesn't allow to make use of any function or stored procedure.

Below is the function definition for reference:-

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetConstantValue](@QueryID INT)
RETURNS  
    @Constantvalue TABLE
    (
        name_ NVARCHAR(2000)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Query NVARCHAR(max) = SELECT code FROM QUERY_TABLE WHERE ID = @QueryID
    Declare @StartIndex int = 0,@EndIndex int = 0,@Count int =  0,@ConstStr nvarchar(max) = ''
    WHILE @Count <= LEN(@Query)
    BEGIN

        IF SUBSTRING(@Query,@Count, 1) = CHAR(39)
        BEGIN
            IF @StartIndex <> 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @ConstStr = @ConstStr + CASE WHEN LEN(@ConstStr)>0 THEN '|' ELSE '' END+ SUBSTRING(@Query,@StartIndex+1,@Count-(@StartIndex+1)) 
                    SET @StartIndex = 0 
                    SET @EndIndex = 0
                
                END
            ELSE
                IF SUBSTRING(@Query,@Count-20, 20) LIKE '%name%[=]%' 
                    SET @StartIndex = @Count
        END
    SET @Count = @Count + 1

    END
    INSERT INTO @Constantvalue
    SELECT Value FROM string_split(@ConstStr,'|')
 
 RETURN
  END
```

Please suggest me a way to achieve this in the main query itself without making any function calls

Comment: then don't make any function , use the code inside the function anywhere that is needed.

Comment: This, in truth, just sounds like a huge design flaw, with an injection issue waiting to happen. Why are you even storing SQL data in a table in the first place?

Comment: @eshirvana The function uses while loop, and i am not sure of how to use while loop in query

Comment: @Larnu This table stores information from a tool and there is a provision of using all sort of scripts including SQL query in the tool. I Hope it gives you some insights about the context.

Comment: So what's the big deal - you search for the literal string. You might get some false positives but nothing will be perfect. And you seem to focus on the use of "=" in relation to the string. And in a specific arrangement ('X' = col is the same as col = 'X' in a comparison). But are not other operators equally suspect? "IN" comes to mind.

Comment: @SMor MY intention is to find a way to search the literal in a query using a query without using a function.